# Ghostscript rotate pdf page 180°

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Would like to rotate all pages of a pdf-file by 180°. DOS script of gs 9.16 returns no error but does not rotate or outputs a rotated file. Whats wrong?

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.16\bin\gswin64c" -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH  -c "<</Orientation 2>> setpagedevice"  -sOutputFile="scan0076_rotated180.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -f "scan0076.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to post a file before anyone can likely help you, but you should probably also set `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` when the device is pdfwrite. Otherwise the device will try to orient the pages so that the majority of the text runs left to right.

Oh and your command line has the `-f` incorrectly placed (should be after the setpagedevice). I'd expect that command line to throw an error.